# Adding multiple points to the GraphicLAyer in aRcgis API for JavaScript 3.18

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html5

I am using ArcGis API for JavaScript 3.18 and I wanted to make a simple map with multiple points that display a short description when I click on them but I have issue with defining multiple points on one GraphicLayer, my code for one PictureMarkerSymbol:

```
  map.on("load", function() {
         var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
         var p = new Point(19.466172, 51.774539);
         var s = new PictureMarkerSymbol('hat.png', 32, 32);
         var i = { Wydział: "Ekonomiczno-Socjologiczny", Adres: "Polskiej Organizacji Wojskowej 3/5, 90-255 Łódź", Telefon: "42 635 53 56"};
         var it = new InfoTemplate("EK-SOC");
         var g = new Graphic(p, s, i).setInfoTemplate(it);
        gl.add(g);
        map.addLayer(gl);
      });
```

How I can add more points to the (gl) Layer? I have tried with addMany function but it seems that's only for the newer API (4.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I solved the issue, turns out it was a minor mistake with adding new point. The correct code looks like this:

```
map.on("load", function() {
         var s = new PictureMarkerSymbol('hat.png', 24, 24);

         var gl = new GraphicsLayer();
         var p = new Point(19.466172,51.774539);
         var i = { Wydział: "Ekonomiczno-Socjologiczny", Adres: "Polskiej Organizacji Wojskowej 3/5, 90-255 Łódź", Telefon: "42 635 53 56", www: "http://www.eksoc.uni.lodz.pl/"};
         var it = new InfoTemplate("Ekonomiczno-Socjologiczny");
         var g = new Graphic(p, s, i).setInfoTemplate(it);

         gl.add(g);

         var p2 = new Point(19.487214,51.775752);
         var i2 = { Wydział: "Zarządzania", Adres: "Jana Matejki 22/26, 90-237 Łódź", Telefon: "42 635 51 22", www: "http://www.wz.uni.lodz.pl/"};
         var it2 = new InfoTemplate("Zarządzania");
         var g2 = new Graphic(p2, s, i2).setInfoTemplate(it2);

        gl.add(g2);

 map.addLayer(gl);
```

I Hope that it will help someone!